# Alternatives to XML shredding in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I tried to shred XML into a temporary table by using XQuery `.nodes` as follows. But, I got performance problem. It is taking much time to shred. Please give me an idea on alternatives for this.

My requirement is to pass bulk records to a stored procedure and parse those records and do some operation based on record values.

```
 CREATE TABLE #DW_TEMP_TABLE_SAVE(  
[USER_ID] [NVARCHAR](30), 
[USER_NAME] [NVARCHAR](255)
)   

insert into #DW_TEMP_TABLE_SAVE
   select 
       A.B.value('(USER_ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(30)' ) [USER_ID], 
       A.B.value('(USER_NAME)[1]', 'nvarchar(30)' ) [USER_NAME]
   from 
       @l_n_XMLDoc.nodes('//ROW') as A(B)
```

Comment: Look into XML-indexes, and schemacollections. Basically, XML-shredding in SQL Server has a way of being insanely slow, until you find a way to put the data somewhere you can index it, and preferably even on an XML column typed as a specific schemacollection. Together they can make an operation that lasted for days, take no longer than 30 seconds for instance (that's what happened with me). Check here for a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233/the-best-way-to-shred-xml-data-into-sql-server-database-columns

Comment: Try to avoid using an XPath expression of `//Row` - that's **not** good for performance! Be **more specific** with your XPath!

Comment: @Kahn Using XML indexes and especially the selective XML indexes in SQL Server 2012 SP1 can be a good thing but only if your data is stored in a table. Here the source is a XML variable `@l_n_XMLDoc`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Making XPath more specific made some difference for me.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: You're right, in which case it's good to know that those options are open should there be a need to change the variable to a table, at least temporarily. I've had a similar scenario where initially some large amount of XML data was stored in a variable and had to find a way to increase the performance. In which case the solution was indeed to put it into a table so it could be indexed and made to use the proper schemacollection. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `text()` node in your values clause.

```sql
insert into #DW_TEMP_TABLE_SAVE
select A.B.value('(USER_ID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(30)' ) [USER_ID], 
       A.B.value('(USER_NAME/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(30)' ) [USER_NAME]
from @l_n_XMLDoc.nodes('/USER_DETAILS/RECORDSET/ROW') as A(B)
```

Not using `text()` will create a query plan that tries concatenate the values from the specified node with all its child nodes and I guess you don't want that in this scenario. The concatenation part of the query if you don't use `text()` is done by the UDX operator and it is a good thing not to have it in your plan.

[image]

Another thing to try is [OPENXML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx). In some scenarios (large xml documents) I have found that OPENXML performs faster.

```sql
declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @l_n_XMLDoc

insert into #DW_TEMP_TABLE_SAVE
select USER_ID, USER_NAME
from openxml(@idoc, '/USER_DETAILS/RECORDSET/ROW', 2) 
  with (USER_ID  nvarchar(30), USER_NAME nvarchar(30))

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Specifying text() made some improvement for me.

Comment: Its not some improvement, its huge. It worked for me with both 'MORE SPECIFIC IN XPATH' and 'text() NODE IN VALUE CLAUSE'. I want to make your answer as ACCEPTED ONE.For that, Please edit your answer to have @l_n_XMLDoc.nodes('//RECORDSET/ROW').

Comment: Sample XML for the question : <USER_DETAILS><GENERAL_INFO><LANG_ID></LANG_ID><USER_ID></USER_ID><ROLE_ID></ROLE_ID><FOR_RVW_SYNC /></GENERAL_INFO><SAS_FLAG></SAS_FLAG><RECORDSET><ROW><SEL>0</SEL><USER_ID></USER_ID><USER_NAME></USER_NAME><PASSWORD></PASSWORD></ROW><ROW><SEL>0</SEL><USER_ID></USER_ID><USER_NAME></USER_NAME><PASSWORD></PASSWORD></ROW></RECORDSET><CUSTOMER_INFO><SAAS_CUSTOMER_ID></SAAS_CUSTOMER_ID></CUSTOMER_INFO></USER_DETAILS>

Comment: It is there. <RECORDSET><ROW>

Comment: No. <USER_DETAILS> is the root node. And, <RECORDSET> is its child. This, <RECORDSET> will contain 1000's of <ROW> nodes.